# Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Source image is in the 'broken' state

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to use canvas in react and typescript, there is my code:

it's render html:

```
public render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <input type="radio" id={'repeatRadio'}/>sdf
            <canvas id={'canvas'} width={600} height={300}>
                canvas not supported
            </canvas>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It's componentDidMount function:

```
 public componentDidMount() {
        this.initCanvas();
    }

    private initCanvas = () => {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        const repeatRadio = document.getElementById('repeatRadio') as HTMLElement;
        const image = new Image();

        image.src = 'test.jpg';
        repeatRadio.onclick = () => {
          this.fill(image,'repeat');
        };

        ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
        image.onload = () => {
            this.fill(image, 'repeat');
        }

    };
    private fill = (image: any, str: string) => {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        debugger;
        const pattern = ctx.createPattern(image,str);

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
        ctx.fill();

    };
```

It's can run before I click input radio, but It's appear err like title when i click.

I add onerror code:

```
image.onerror = (message) => {
    console.error(message);
}
```

I get info as fallow:
[image]

But I can't find something useful.

Comment: check your dev tools' network panel, it will probably tell you in which way it failed to load your resource.

Comment: my image is well, and I test another image is same error, others, image's path is right.

Comment: I see the network panel, and the image resource is 304, I don't know what lead this.

Comment: I disable caching and get 200. But also get same error when I click.

Comment: Are you able to load this same image by directly setting its url in the address bar? What if you add `image.onerror = console.error`?

Answer (score 0):

Image will have to be imported in react using import clause.

```
import TEXTURE_IMG1 from '../textures/honey_im_subtle.png'
```

Once imported you can assign it 'src' property.

```
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = TEXTURE_IMG1;
    var texturePatternBrush = new fabric.PatternBrush(this.canvas);
```